# Carbon get sunday next 2 weeks

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How I can get sunday of next 2 weeks?

I have code:

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse('last sunday of this month'); //last sunday every second week ?
```

But How I can get last sunday every second week?

Example: I need get 18 february, after I need get 4 march, e.t.c..

```
$interval = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::weeks(2);
$startDate = $startDate->add($interval);

return $startDate->toDateString(); //19 february, but not 18. Why??
```

Comment: Can you make some clear about Sunday ? You need next two sunday from the start date or some thing else

Comment: I need get last sunday every second week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `CarbonInterval::weeks()` method to create an interval and the `add()` method to add this interval to the `Carbon` date:

```
$interval = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::weeks(2);
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $startDate->add($interval)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain loop variable `$i` over there, which is not used inside loop :D

Comment: @SagarGautam it's just an example of printing ten Sundays with an interval of 2 weeks.

Comment: But why you use loop?

Comment: @Jadasdas loop is just an example. Just try it and you'll see how it works.

Comment: How I can get last sunday of second week without loop? I need get last sunday, how in example in my answer.

Comment: @Jadasdas `$interval = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::weeks(2); $sunday = $startDate->add($interval); $nextSunday = $startDate->add($interval);`

Comment: I get 24 february. Why?

Comment: @Jadasdas this is how your code works for me https://ibb.co/cHkB1H It looks like you didn't show the exact code you're using and you're doing something between the first line of the code you've shown and the rest of it.